# How can I access a client side dll from a server side application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, .net-4.0

In my current project we are trying to integrate a card reader into a
website. The problem is that we have to have the Windows Service
sitting on the clients machine in order for the card reader to work.

The purpose of the website is to have the client scan the card through
the card reader and have the information be sent to the database
through a web service. After the information is saved to the database
it can then be retrieved and shown on the site.

The question I have is
how can I access a .dll, that I have written, from the the asp page
sitting on the server. I know that I could use ActiveX but I am trying to
access the .dll in a way that will allow me to have the webpage be used in
as many browsers as possible.

I am thinking of using silverlight to try and access the dll. The .dll in
question is one that I have written and am trying to access. I've also looked
at trying the DLLImport but I've not been able to get it to work. I am currently using
.NET 4.0 and am writing in C#.

Comment: oh. good. downloading a dll from a website and executing it. this is why ActiveX was such a moronic idea in the beginning. "no one on the interwebz is ever nasty. let's trust everything!".

Comment: @MarcB indeed - and also why web-apps don't solve everything!

Comment: I would suggest your solution is flawed. The client needs a proper installed app that can access the card reader and communicate with the server via REST/SOAP or whatever. Allowing the server to supply code that can access a dll installed on the client isn't just a massive security risk, it's also an architectural disaster.

Comment: @DavidArno, agreed on all fronts - but might also add that the REST api (*vomits at SOAP* ;) ), needs to be over HTTPS.

Comment: You really need get a better specification. This solution just sounds wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client is reading a smartcard, it might be a good idea to use the [built-in windows features to use a smartcard to authenticate to IIS on the remote computer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732116.aspx). If you're trying to read anything else from the smartcards, then it's usually better to offer the client a normal installer that registers itself as a security device, Browsers have built-in functionality to communicate to such a device. Our local bank, ABN AMRO, uses such a device which is sold by [Todos AB](http://www.todos.se/) and which comes with a driver that works in this fashion.

If you want to do anything else with the smartcard (anything other than reading a certificate or a security token, you'll probably have no other option than to offer the user with a download that I'd personally would always deny.

Comment: I may have misspoke(typed?) this is a card reader that is scanning in cards such as Drivers Licenses and storing the information to the database. This is used to help make sure that the license is a valid one as well as any other relevant information. I have been doing more research on it and it seems as if Silverlight may be way to work with this project